# Count when two values exist in column B with the same value in column A

Tags: excel, match, sumproduct

I have a database which looks like this (attached)

[image]

And I am trying to see if 8808 has played each of the players from cell E5 downwards.

I have tried SUMPRODUCT formulae, but this did not work!

Thanks for the help, really stuck on this one

Comment: You should perhaps cease referring to excel as a database..

Comment: Thanks so much for the help Caius. The time you took to write that comment has really helped me. Thank you.

Comment: What version of Excel is this for? Office 365?

Comment: Yep, the latest :)

Comment: I should add that it's possible to pull a list of 8808's races using the FILTER function. Might help solve it.

Comment: It doesn't look like any of the numbers in column E are in column B.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Assuming the data occupying columns A and B is held within a table named **Table1**, in `F6`:

`=IF(SUM(COUNTIFS(Table1[Player ID],E6,Table1[Race ID],UNIQUE(FILTER(Table1[Race ID],Table1[Player ID]=F$3)))),"Yes","No")`

and copied down.

Comment: No worries! Actually, that formula already uses the calculation for how many times they've raced, so maybe start with that, i.e. `=SUM(COUNTIFS(Table1[Player ID],E6,Table1[Race ID],UNIQUE(FILTER(Table1[Race ID],Table1[Player ID]=F$3))))` and then you could add a simple formula alongside that to check if it's greater than zero to indicate whether they've raced or not.